# mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1698): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' - getting this error after my mac restarted itself

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have Valet up and running on my computer - it was working fine until yesterday when my computer restarted and now I am getting this error

mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1698): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

I dont understand why it would be working one day and then broken the next...

I am worried changing any settings will break it more as it was working prior to yesterday...

**EDIT:** other questions that are similar don't seem to work on MariaDB if I try and change privileges or update users I get this error ---

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'BY 'root'' at line 1

Comment: Check syntax error, may be try running SQL query manually first.

Comment: They definitely are as I can access through sudo mysql -u root and brew services mariadb is started

Answer (score 0):

Check your `.env` file; and confirm it against `config/database.php`; check if the credentials provided are correct.

Comment: whereabouts would these files be located?

Comment: in application folder @JaimeePage